# Ошибка с messages.send

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Выполняю запрос к API ВКонтакте с помощью SDK (отправка сообщения из аккаунта в сообщения паблика):

```
String ID_Group = "-тут_ID_моего_паблика";
String message = "Test";

VKRequest request = new VKRequest("messages.send", VKParameters.from("peer_id", ID_Group, "message", message));
```

При выполнении появляется ошибка:

> code1: 100; One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: peer_id is accepted only from version 5.38

Я понимаю,  что оно пишет. Пробовал даже передавать version (5.38 и 5.60), но не помогло. Та же ошибка. И самое интересное, что на сайте https://vk.com/dev/messages.send в их форме ввожу всего 2 параметра (ID группы со знаком минус и текст сообщения) и сообщение отправляется. Проверял во входящих в паблике. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Может потому, что ID_Group должен быть целым числом, а вы строку даете?

Comment: Пробовал писать с минусом без кавычек. Результат тот же.

Comment: попробуйте инициализировать SDK вызовом [`VKSdk.customInitialize`](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/VKSdk.java#L133) вместо `VKSdk.initialize`, там можно указать версию API.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением в ресурсы приложения (strings.xml) строки:

```
string name="com_vk_sdk_ApiVersion">5.38</string
```